# Symfony Form not saving data in many to many Association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony

I have below association between entites.

**users**:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Esec\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="owner")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_companies",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $company;
```

And

**companies**:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="company",)
     */
    private $owner;
```

There is a form `CompanyType` to create company, and set his owner who is currently login.
I do this after the form submitted,

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                            $company->setOwner($this->getUser());
                            $em->persist($company);
                            $em->flush();
                            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('esec_company_index'));
                        }
```

The Company is Saved in Company table, but not their owner in `user_companies` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you don't add the new `Company` entity to the Collection `$company` of `User`. Add `$this->getUser()->addCompany($company);` in your Controller and this should do the trick. You could also do that automatically inside `setOwner`.

Comment: em trying to query to load all the companies list owned by a user. i have this query but it didn't work. `  $repository = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User');
                $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->innerJoin('u.company', 'companies')
                    ->where('u.id = :user')
                    ->setParameter('user', $this->getUser()->getId())
                    ->getQuery();`

Comment: If you want to query Companies, get the Company Repository instead of the User Repository. `$em->getRepository('Company')->createQueryBuilder('c')->innerJoin('c.owner', 'owner') ->where('owner.id = :user')->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use wrong association between entities for that case. Instead of `Many-To-Many`, you should use `One-To-Many`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Esec\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="owner")
 */
private $company;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="company")
 */
private $owner;
```